# Get Payer information from PayPal before transaction

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-adaptive-payments

I have a weird scenario. In my application (which is fundraising application) there are two types of users.

1. Registered users
2. Non registered users

Both types of users can pay with PayPal, and I am using PayPal adaptive payments PHP SDK for this. According to PayPal I had to restrict both types of users so they can't pay more than FOUR time to the same fundraiser. Registered users can be restricted and its quite clear to me, but how I can restrict non registered users ? Thoughts ?

My model which failed (And I give it a try): First I was thinking about IPN because IPN return payer email address so I thought I will save this email in my database and then I can count that email against that specific fundraiser, but this model fails as I can not compare because the payer enter his email address only when he is being redirected to PayPal, and I can capture his email via IPN only after he was pay while I need this before he pays.

Is there any service PayPal provide that I can know how much time a user(Account) pay to another user(Account) regardless of the amount of money.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this 4 payments rule you're referring to..??  can you provide more detail on that?